# Non-real coefficients, but real roots

Tags: polynomials

Say I want to provide an example of a polynomial with non-real coefficients, but with real roots.

A trivial example to provide is $P(x)=ix-i$, which has non-real coefficients but a real root $x=1$. However, I feel that this is a 'cheat example' if that makes sense, because the coefficients just cancel out anyway. Is there a 'less cheating' example out there?

Comment: Any polynomial with all real roots can be factored as a monic polynomial with all real coefficients times some constant. Did you mean for the complex polynomial to just have some real roots?

Comment: Yes, I meant a complex (taking complex -> non-real) polynomial that has real roots.

Comment: So, something like $(1-i)x^2+(1+i)x$ then?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want *all* coefficients to be non-real and *all* roots to be real?

Comment: Correct, lemon. Like my example, all the coefficients are non-real, but its only root is real. I'm just looking for a more non-obvious example and how to construct such examples.

Comment: How do you expect that to work? Suppose the roots are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$. We know the polynomial is $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dots(x-\alpha_n)$. When you expand that, all the coefficients will come out real. So any example is bound to be a "cheating" example.

Comment: If the $n$-th degree polynomial $P(x)$ has $n$ real roots $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ (including multiplicities), then $P(x) = C(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_n)$ for some constant $C$. If you multiply out $(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_n)$, then you will get a polynomial with all real coefficients. Hence, the only polynomials which satisfy your conditions are real polynomials multiplied by a complex constant.

Comment: That makes sense and that is sufficient as an answer for me, thank you. Can you re-post that as an answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an $n$-th degree polynomial $P(x)$ which has only real roots. Let the $n$ real roots be $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ (including multiplicities). Then $P(x) = C(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_n)$ for some constant $C$. If you multiply out $(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_n)$, then you will get a polynomial with all real coefficients. Hence, the only polynomials which satisfy your conditions are real polynomials multiplied by a complex constant.